# ManifestPlaceholder convert NumericString to actual number?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest, build.gradle

I'm using ManifestPlaceholder to store some Key in my gradle.build, that could be then use in AndroidManifest.xml eventually. It works fine for my Fabric.io key, but not for my Facebook Key.

The reason is, in my Fabric.io key, it contacts numbers and alphabets. So it is preserved as a String. But since the Facebook key is all number (although it's String), it get converted to some other random number.

More clearer illustration below.

**As expected** if I set the ManifestPlaceholder as below

```
    manifestPlaceholders = [facebook_app_id: "12345678901234G"]
```

And in my AndroidManifest.xml as

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="${facebook_app_id}" />
```

I will get my ID retained in generated AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="12345678901234G" />
```

**However** if I set something that is fully numeric as below

```
    manifestPlaceholders = [facebook_app_id: "123456789012345"]
```

While my AndroidManifest.xml is the same

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="${facebook_app_id}" />
```

It becomes something as below in my generated AndroidManifest.xml.

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="1457557760.000000" />
```

Why did it change my numerical String? How could I preserve it as a String?

Comment: May I know your Gradle version? I am using classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0' it work on my machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I verify this works as expected with Android gradle plugin `2.3.0` and Gradle plugin version `3.4.1`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I can no longer replicate the issue as well.